# Problema com a Session entre Sidekiq e Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Por algum motivo após o processamento do Job no Sidekiq a Session cai.

Segue o fluxo e mais detalhe sobre o problema.

[image: Fluxo Básico]

Segue código do Job:

```
class GenerateProfileJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :profile

  def perform(login)
    user = User.find_by_login(login)

    import_github(user)
    profile_generate(user)
    #NOTE: Não será enviado email ainda
    # send_profile(user)
    evaluations_count(user)
  end

  def import_github(user)
    Github::Importation.new.run user
  end

  def profile_generate(user)
    Profile::Generate.new(user).run
  end

  def send_profile(user)
    ProfileMailer.with(user: user).evaluation_completed.deliver_now
  end

  def evaluations_count(user)
    user.update(evaluations_count: user.evaluations_count.to_i + 1)
  end
end
```

No fluxo quando ocorre o Redirect fica tudo normal com a Session.

Somente a após o fim do processamento do Job que a Session cai.

Outro teste que fiz foi deixar o Sidekiq desligado, pois assim a Session não cai.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: qual é o código do seu job? é qualquer job que acontece?

Comment: Vou adicionar o código do Job no post e verificar se acontece para qualquer Job.

Comment: o job pode está invalidando o token de autenticacao ou invalidando o usuario.

Comment: Era o usuário mesmo, consegui resolver. Um código antigo, sabe Deus pq, dar update no password do user, dentro do import_github